# Garage door opens only partially in hot weather

Tags: garage-door-opener

My Craftsman garage door opened works fine in cool weather  or early in the morning. When the weather is hot, it opens partially, from 1/8 of the way to 7/8 of the way. Pressing the remote closes it, and pressing again it opens it, but less than the first time. Doing that again it opens even less.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any adjustment knobs on the motorized unit? Mine used to do the same, but only the left door. I turned the lifting torque up an 8th of a turn.

Comment: Chain, belt, or screw drive? When was the last time you lubricated the opener, rails and wheels? Different types of openers have different lubrication procedures - check the manual, but generally it's recommended to do this once a year.

Answer (score 2):

1. Step one - when it's hot and acting up, close the door, disconnect
   the opener, and open it manually. If thermal expansion is making the
   door bind, you need to address the basic mechanical issues of the
   door mechanism BEFORE you start cranking up the door opener. Clean, lubricate, adjust, or call a garage door mechanic, as apprpriate to the issues and your skills.
2. Then go though the complete adjustment procedure for your opener, including the safety tests that are supposed to be run every 6 months or so (stops when beam broken, stops and reverses when hitting a 2x4 laid flat on the floor, closes and stops correctly when nothing is in the way, opens correctly. At this point you may adjust the force if the mechanics are correct.
3. If you've done those things and it still acts up when hot, or if your adjustment procedure doesn't seem to work as it should if you do it when it's hot, you may have a problem (evidently of a thermal nature, or aggravated by heat) in the logic board of the opener. I had some very puzzling behavior from an opener once that appeared to have been caused by a nearby lighting strike scrambling it's little brains, and making it into a potential killer (it was trying to drive the garage door through the floor when it closed.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The unit is 1/2 hp chain-drive. I have not found any sticking place.  I replaced the logic board about 3 yrs ago and it looks like I may need to do it again.